# ActiveRecord scope does not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a following relation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :incoming_delegations,
    :class_name => "Delegation", :foreign_key => :to_user_id,
    :conditions => { :active => true }
  #...
end
```

and

```
class Delegation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :from_user, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :to_user,   :class_name => "User"

  scope :from, lambda { |user| where(:from_user_id => user.id) }
  scope :to, lambda { |user| where(:to_user_id => user.id) }
  #...
end
```

Now when I do

```
Delegation.from(User.find(43)) # I get list of delegations from user
User.last.incoming_delegations # I get list of incoming delegations
```

but when I try:

```
User.last.incoming_delegations.from(User.find(43))
```

then I get following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot visit User
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:25:in `rescue in visit'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:281:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_JoinSource'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:135:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectCore'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/mysql.rb:41:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectCore'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:121:in `block in visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:121:in `map'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:121:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/mysql.rb:36:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:19:in `visit'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:5:in `accept'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/to_sql.rb:19:in `accept'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/arel-3.0.2/lib/arel/visitors/bind_visitor.rb:11:in `accept'
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:7:in
        from /home/jiri/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@OM/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:18:i
... 1 levels...
```

any idea what cause this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scope :from, lambda { |user| where(:from_user_id => user.id) }
```

`from` is a bad name for a scope; **name it something else**.

**[This `from` method](https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/nodes/select_core.rb#L20)** within ARel is being used when you're trying to call the `:from` scope in your `Delegation` class.